# how can I solve this Error "ufunc 'subtract' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')"?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to normalize my dataframe for forecasting algorithm in normalizing I get this error

If I want to explain more my dataframe is like this format with 1991 rows × 1691 columns dimensions

| Code | CallTime | 211323 | 224250 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6968 | 2022-04-26 02:44:24.373376 | 61800000.0 | 133200000.0 |

and my code is:

```
column_indices = {name: i for i, name in enumerate(Code.columns)}

n = len(df1)
train_df = df1[0:int(n*0.7)]
val_df = df1[int(n*0.7):int(n*0.9)]
test_df = df1[int(n*0.9):]

num_features = df1.shape[1]
train_mean = train_df.mean()
train_std = train_df.std()

train_df = (train_df - train_mean) / train_std
val_df = (val_df - train_mean) / train_std
test_df = (test_df - train_mean) / train_std
```

then I get this error:

> ufunc 'subtract' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')

help me please.

Comment: It could be that you have some data corruption. It looks like that at some point you're trying to subtract a float from a datetime. From the provided info, try to have a look at your `CallTime` column. You might have some probs there.

Comment: Your question does not really provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). e.g. provide a larger portion of your dataframe. Go ahead and test the code you present above on that exact same dataframe portion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most probably have a problem with the values in your `CallTime` column. Take this example that result in the same error:

```
time_s = pd.Series([pd.Timestamp.now() + pd.Timedelta(seconds=x) for x in range(10)])

# this will raise: numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncBinaryResolutionError: ufunc 'subtract' cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')
error_operation = time_s - 2.0
```

Suggestion: make sure `df1['CallTime'].dtype` is a datetime format:

```
time_s.dtype
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Comment: could it be from "Code"? cause I use pivot table to make this dataframe and after that I re index on Code and now it happened

Comment: I tried your code but I get this error now?  **unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'float'**

Comment: @Behy you need to have a look at what kind of operations you can do with datetime and timedeltas. e.g. `pd.Timestamp.now() - 2.0` results in something similar to what you report in your comment, but `pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.Timedelta(seconds=2.0)` would work. So in all, your logic is flawed somewhere. As stated in the answer, ensure that your dtypes are compatible.